# OpenLayers 3: Add a drop down select scale option

Tags: javascript, openlayers

In OpenLayers 3.9.0 .I have default scale for OpenLayers 3 but what user want is able to set the scale like 1:2000 or 1:5000 and so on using a drop down select box.

something like the image below.

[image]

Comment: You can create a [custom control](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.9.0/apidoc/ol.control.Control.html).

Comment: any idea where to start. I looked up i found resolution but how can i extract scale from resolution. what is the relation in between scale, resolution and zoom level ?

Comment: Well, if @ThomasB solution suits to you, great, if you want an extended `ol.control.Control` like [this](https://github.com/jonataswalker/ol3-geocoder), then there's a little work ahead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the current Scale I found this answer in Google Groups:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/ol3-dev/RAJa4locqaM/Tg-JQ9L_YeMJ

Another useful part can be found here:
https://github.com/bartvde/geoserver-ol3-preview/blob/master/index-ol3.html
(the section starting with "map.getView().on('change:resolution', ..." )

I set up a working example here: http://jsfiddle.net/expedio/ks9t826k/

As the API of ol3 is still changing a lot I am still working much more with OpenLayers2. Perhaps someone who is already a bit more familiar with ol3 can have a look at this jsfiddle and tell if there is a better solution than this ;)

Comment: looks promising, I will get back after trying it . Thanks Thomas B.